# Average CPU and RAM Usage for a Fortigate machine

Tags: networking, fortigate

I manage a Fortigate machine onsite and I want to create a 7 day average usage of our CPU and RAM.

Can't seem to find anyway to do it' looked everywhere and it seems nobody tried doing it.

I have FortiCLoud turned on but all the metrics it shows are about Network usage.

I kindly ask for an idea :)

Comment: Can you poll these values programmatically, or can you export the values somehow? Have you reviewed the Fortigate documentation regarding this?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to poll the values or any export. 

I tried reading documentaion, found no reference about average usage, only current usage.

Comment: Oh, why? You can use the current and save it in a spreadsheet and then get the average from that. You're asking the product to store its own logs for a period of time and then use more processing power to compute some arbitrary "friendly" values. If that isn't already baked into the system, then I doubt they'll be able to just server it to you. Just export the current data and use a table to do those computations yourself.

Comment: That sounds like work, which I'm trying to avoid. 

But yeah, I could log in every hour and log the value and create my own averages.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer:

It appears the system doesn't have any built in or "native" way ot providing the requested info, so you'll need to pull the data is DOES give and use that to create the reports you want.

I cannot speak to whether this data can be pulled programmatically or exported automatically, but given the point-in-time or current resource usage, pulled at regular intervals, you can use a spreadsheet to store that data and then compute the information you require, such as the averaged.

Once you've got the data, there will be few limits on what you can calculate from that data on your own, so I advise that as you build this spreadsheet you store the data on one table without significant modification, and put any computation or presentation on separate tables/sheets.